# Getting access to a ListView control from the another onClick method control

Tags: android, onclick, listactivity

How can I get access to the, for example, TextView, from the onClick method assigned to the, for example, ImageView? The TextView and ImageView make up the ListView item.

In my item.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="onImgClick"
    />      
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in my ListActivity I have onImgClick method:

```
 public void onImgClick(View v) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText("Hello world!");
}
```

But the View v - this is ImageView, so in this method I have Fatal Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

on the line:

```
tv.setText("Hello world!");
```

I know this isn't correct way to get access to the TextView. And I know that I can use onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) according to the whole ListView. but I want to achieve this from the ImageView onClick method.

Comment: If ImageView and TextView form a listview item, then they are child views of the item in the listview, so you are gaining access to the childs with the parent...You can achieve (I guess so) it but the onclick method will be assigned only on the top of the listview not on all items...

Comment: Yes, I can do something like that. Or use onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) method according to the whole ListView. But I want to find solution from ImageView onClick method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. I need only to set id on my LinearLayout:

```
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
```

And next do something like that:

```
public void onImgClick(View v) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();       
    TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);        
    textView.setText("Hello world!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your easiest way to access the TextView is through a Handler and use sendMessage:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Alternatively, depending on how you've implemented it, you might want to look into getParent(), as in `v.getParent().findViewById(r.id.text);`

I am not sure if that works for your case though.

Comment: To the second method: `v.getParent().` - I don't have here findViewById() method. By the way when I do something like that: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), v.getParent().toString(), 0).show();` I can see as a parent View android.widget.LinearLayout.

Comment: If I want to use a Handler and sendMessage I must have my TextView declared in my class (if I understand it). But I have the ListView with a count of items, and when I am clicking the ImageView I can't get access to the TextView in ImageView onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

set on an onclick listener the listview in the getView method of your listview.

Comment: Could you give me more details? Do you mean something like that mbarnes recommended to me?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you override the ListAdapter and in getView() set the listener to the parent View. Use setTag() to make identity easier.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

...

getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
 LinearLayout thisview = null;
 if(convertView == null){
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent);
 }

 TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

 ImageView img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
 img.setTag("uniqueid_"+position);

 //this will put a reference to the TextView in the ImageView
 img.setKey("TEXT_VIEW", tv);

 img.setOnClickListener(this);
 ...
 return convertView;
}
```

You can then get the TextView with v.getKey("TEXT_VIEW") in the onClick()... but it seems like a good potential for memory leaks.

Comment: But how can I use getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method in my onImgClick method? In onImgClick I have only one parametr - View.